# How can I plot this sum with sympy plot or matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, sum, sympy

Hello I started to work with sympy. **So I got this function and my question is how can I plot this sum. I tried it with sp.plot and plt.plot, but it doesn't work. I just want a coordinate system. I always get Errors like** *The same variable should be used in all univariate expressions being plotted.* Probably it is a very easy task, but how I said I just started with sympy and don't know how to go on.
Thanks for all answers!

```
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = sp.symbols("k")
n = sp.symbols("n")
a = sp.Sum(((-1)**k)*(x**(2*k+1))/sp.factorial(((2*k+1))), (k, 0, n))
```

Comment: You need to substitute a value for `n` like `plot(a.subs(n, 10))`. Otherwise the expression can not be numerically evaluated at any given x value.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what exactly you want to plot, especially as your `x` is not declared nor explained.

To plot an expression using a `Sum`, the expression should be evaluated.  Some fixed `n`s and `x`s will be needed.  Also, `.doit()` needs to be called to force sympy to evaluate the sum.

Here is an example, supposing you want to draw curves for `x` in steps between -7.5 and 7.5, and for `n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...`. `lambdify` can be used to convert a sympy expression to a numpy function. Update: As suggested in the comments, a change of the limits.

```py
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = sp.symbols("x")
k = sp.symbols("k", integer=True, positive=True)
n = sp.symbols("n", integer=True, positive=True)
a = sp.Sum(((-1) ** k) * (x ** (2 * k + 1)) / sp.factorial(((2 * k + 1))), (k, 0, n))

for n_val in range(1, 11):
    a_np = sp.lambdify(x, a.subs(n, n_val).doit())
    x_vals = np.linspace(-9, 9, 1000)
    plt.plot(x_vals, a_np(x_vals), label=n_val)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.margins(x=0)
plt.legend(title='n', bbox_to_anchor=[1.02, 1.02], loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plotting a sympy sum]

Instead of plotting the curves for subsequent `n`s on the same plot, here is a version with each on a different subplot.

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=5, nrows=2, figsize=(12, 5))
for n_val, ax in zip(range(1, 11), axs.flat):
    a_np = sp.lambdify(x, a.subs(n, n_val).doit())
    x_vals = np.linspace(-12, 12, 1000)
    ax.plot(x_vals, a_np(x_vals), label=n_val, color='dodgerblue')
    ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
    ax.margins(x=0)
    ax.set_title(f'n = {n_val}')
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

[image: plotting sympy sums on subplots]

Comment: You could use `np.linspace(-7.5, 7.5, 1000)` and add `plt.axis([-7.5, 7.5, -2, 2])` to get the interessting parts of the plot